# AWS Lambda layer has no execute permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I create a lambda lambda for Python runtime (3.6 and 3.7 compatible) that contains a bin executable (texlive)

But when I try to execute it through `subprocess.run` it says that it has no execution permissions!

How can I make it so this layer has execute permissions? I zipped the layer files on Windows 10 so I'm not sure how to add Linux execute permission.

Also, as far as I know when you unzip a file it "resets" the permissions, so if AWS is not setting the execute permissions when unzipping my layers, what can I do?

By the way, I'm uploading my layer via the aws console

Comment: what is the layer zip folder structure?

Comment: I tried `/`, `/bin` and `/lib`, it doesn't make a difference, it seems to inherit the permissions inside the zip

Comment: the layers are actually available in the ```/opt``` folder. You can find more about it in this blog post:  https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d

Comment: @RepakulaSrushith I know that, it's not related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the WSL on Windows 10 and zipped up my layer using the *zip* executable from within Ubuntu:

```
zip -r importtime_wrapper_layer.zip .
```

It created a zip file that retained the 755 file permissions on my script.

I was able to view that the correct attributes were present using 7zip and the Lambda runtime was able to execute it.